# SQL - Check if IDs contains same ID's value

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder how can I check if two users (**user_id**) are in the same thread (**thread_id**) without passing the (**thread_id**) using SQL, through the structure of the table below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all threads where those 2 users are in you can do

```
select thread_id
from your_table
where user_id in (1,2)
group by thread_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2
```

To get all threads that have more than one user do

```
select thread_id
from your_table    
group by thread_id
having count(distinct user_id) >= 2
```

Comment: juergen,
Thanks for your help! =)
I think I found a problem, how do I know which user it will have to put in distinct because as below, the SQL would not work.

select *
from participant_thread
where user_id in (2, 3)
group by thread_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 3

Comment: Put the number of users you put into the `where` clause. if your have  `where user_id in (1,3,7,9)` then use `having count(distinct user_id) = 4`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very well what you wanted but as I understand it , I assume that this is.

```
select thread_id, COUNT(thread_id) AS dup_count  from participant_thread as participant
GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING (COUNT(thread_id) > 1)
```

[result scrypt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/towu3.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
select thread_id, user_id
from thread.thread_table
where thread_id in (
    select thread_id
    from thread.thread_table
    group by thread_id
    having count(user_id) > 1
);
```